# Back up stacktrace at runtime

Tags: c#, debugging, constraints

This might seem like an odd question but google is not giving me anything to go on.

I have some extension methods that allow me to evaluate return values and so forth on demand. I use them in places where Contracts don't really do what I want.

What these extension methods do is a combination of old school Debug.Assert() and a 'for realsies' check that throws an exception if the conditional is not met. I have others that allow you to throw a specific exception as well. Example:

```
public static void IsNotNullOrEmpty(this System.Collections.ICollection input, string message = default(string), bool throwOnFailure = true)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
                    Debug.Assert(input != null && input.Count > 0, message);

                if (input == null || input.Count == 0 && throwOnFailure)
                    throw new ArgumentNullException(message);
            }

        public static void IsNotNull<T>(this object input, string message = default(string), bool throwOnFailure = true)  where T : Exception, new()
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
                Debug.Assert(input != null, message);

            if (input == null && throwOnFailure)
            {
                // NOTE - catches the possibility that the Exception class's implementation does not have a constructor that takes a message
                // Have to do it this way because the Message property is readonly on the Exception class so we can't just set it.
                try 
                {
                    throw Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), message) as T;
                } 
                catch(MissingMethodException)  
                {
                    throw new T();
                }
            }
        }
```

They actually work really well. The only problem being that the debug assert snaps the debugger onto the Debug.Assert() line. I'd like it to snap on the line that actually violated the constraint.

So my question is, I can easilly use .GetFrame(1) on a stacktrace to get the MethodInfo for the method that called the constraint. But how do I get the debugger in VS to back up one frame and SHOW that method as if you'd double clicked on it in the callstack window?

There may well be a way to do this with some prepackaged thing on Nuget or what have you but these have served me pretty well so far.

Anybody have an idea?

thanks
E

Comment: You are saying you don't like Debug.Assert().  Well, don't use it then.  Throwing ArgumentNullException when a collection is empty and not null is only guaranteed to get you several very nasty emails.

Comment: That's what inbox filters are for. But no, that's not what I'm saying. I love Debug assert and my code used to be littered with them. But the fact is that the code works differently in debug vs release mode. If I'm checking on a parameter and the check fails I'd rather have it throw an exception in release mode. That's just me, YMMV. But like I said I've had a lot of good experiences with this method of validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is the [DebuggerStepThroughAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggerstepthroughattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

When an exception is thrown in a method tagged with this attribute, the debugger will be placed on the line that called the method, and not inside the method.

In other words, you want to declare your methods like this:

```
[DebuggerStepThrough]
public static void IsNotNullOrEmpty(...)
{
    ...
}

[DebuggerStepThrough]
public static void IsNotNull<T>(...)
    where T : Exception, new()
{
    ...
}
```

Also note that if you use the step into function in the debugger, you will not step into one of these methods but instead step over it as though it was external, which will make debugging *these* methods harder.

You may want to consider placing that attribute inside `#ifdef...#endig` section to make it easy to switch to a configuration that allows you to debug them.

Comment: worth noting that when you do want to actually debug through these methods it becomes a PITA, especially once you forget you put those attributes on the methods.

Answer (score 0):

I am just wondering if you mean this. This is returning the Name of the Method and Class the program was called from.

```
public static bool IsNull(this string value)
{
    var method = new StackTrace().GetFrame(1).GetMethod();
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("I was called from '{0}' of class '{1}'", method.Name, method.DeclaringType));

    return string.IsNullOrEmpty(value);
}
```